# Filter through list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a list of names in a box that I want to filter through based on a user input and filter out names that don't match.  Much like this example :http://www.somacon.com/p241.php.  I am new to Javascript and this is how my names are displayed in the box:

```
<select id="authorSelectId" multiple="multiple" class="accordionSelect">
<c:forEach var="author" items="${dropDownValues.authorDisplayList}">
<option value="${author}">${author}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

And this is my input box for the user:

```
<input onKeyUp="handleKeyUp(20);" type="text" id='functioninput' name="functioninput" VALUE="" style="font-size:10pt;width:34ex;">
```

My code correctly calls my "handleKeyUp(20)" method.  But I am unsure how to link to the "authorSelectId" list of names and filter through those based on "functionInput" text.  If more code is needed, I can provide.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a reference to authorSelectId using:

```
var asi= document.getElementById("authorSelectId");
```

Then, you can iterate over the options like this:

```
for (var i= 0; i < asi.options.length; ++i) {
    var opt= asi.options[i];
    if (opt.selected) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```